# How do I get correct datetime in php according to server time?

Tags: php, datetime

Current server time is

```
[me@unknown ~]# date
Fri Feb 24 14:53:41 MYT 2012
```

When I `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` the date time is `2012-02-24 06:53:46`. The hour, minute & second is not same.

How do I get same date with server time in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the timezone for `MYT` before getting the date, e.g.:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuala_Lumpur');
```

Also see [this example](http://codepad.org/ogn7mu1z).

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set [timezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)